# Regarding the def and return function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

I was writing a program to write the multiplication table of number given by the user.
Here's my code:

```
def mul_table(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(n,"x",i,"=",(n * i))
        i = i + 1
    return(n)
        

x = int(input("Enter the number: "))
x1 = mul_table(x)
print(x1)
```

But in the output it shows the number entered by the user also in the end like this (I know have written the value after "return" but if I leave it empty then it shows None, so how can I get rid of this?):

```
Enter the number: 5
5 x 1 = 5  
5 x 2 = 10 
5 x 3 = 15 
5 x 4 = 20 
5 x 5 = 25 
5 x 6 = 30 
5 x 7 = 35 
5 x 8 = 40 
5 x 9 = 45 
5 x 10 = 50
**5**
```

Can anyone tell me that how can the program return nothing (absolutely nothing, not even the "None" text or the number entered by the user) in PYTHON 3.9.1 ?

Comment: You don't have to print the return value of `mul_table`, nor do you have to store it anywhere. You can just call it.

Comment: A function must return *something*. If you don't explicitly `return` a value, then `None` is the default return value. You simply don't need to `print` the return value of the function. Your function is already printing. Just call it `mul_table(x)` without even saving the result to a variable

Comment: 1st) dont print the returnvalue of the function call ... 2nd) don't increment `i` your range object will give you an incremented i on each loop-around.

Answer (score 2):

Your `mul_table` function handles the printing itself. It needs no return value, and you shouldn't print it even if it exists - you should just call the function:

```
def mul_table(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(n,"x",i,"=",(n * i))
        i = i + 1
    # return statement removed here        

x = int(input("Enter the number: "))
mul_table(x) # No need to capture the return value or print it
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mul_table` method is returning `n` and you are printing it with `print(x1)`. Remove this call to `print` if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues, here is a working version

```
def mul_table(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print(n,"x",i,"=",(n * i))

x = int(input("Enter the number: "))
mul_table(x)
```

1. You print inside the function, so you don't need to call *mul_table* in a print statement
2. You also don't need a *return* statement in the function (though it returns None if you omit the return statement or use a return statement without a return value)
3. *i = i+1* inside the function is wrong, you are using a for statement where *i* gets values 1, 2, ..., 10 successively.